# How to Extract people's last name start with "S" and first name not start with "S"

Tags: regex

As the title shows, how do I capture a person who:

- Last name start with letter "S"
- First name **NOT** start with letter "S"

The expression should match the entire last name, not just the first letter, and first name should **NOT** be matched.

Input string is like the following:

- (Last name) (First name)
- Duncan, Jean
- Schmidt, Paul
- Sells, Simon
- Martin, Jane
- Smith, Peter
- Stephens, Sheila

This is my regular expression:

```
/([S].+)(?:, [^S])/
```

Here is the result I have got:

> Schmidt, P
> Smith, P

the result included "," space & letter "P" which should be excluded.

The ideal match would be

> Schmidt
>
> Smith

Comment: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this pattern: `^S\w+(?=, [A-RT-Z])`.

`^S\w+` matches any word (name in your case) that start with `S` at the beginning,

`(?=, [A-RT-Z])` - positive lookahead - makes sure that what follows, is not the word (first name in your case) starting with `S` (`[A-RT-Z]` includes all caps except `S`).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xL2ZQN/1)

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to catch the initials. I've just updated the code to fit your need. Check it:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   //Your code goes here
   Console.WriteLine(ValidateName("FirstName LastName", 'L'));
}

private static string ValidateName(string name, char letter)
{
   // Split name by space

   string[] names = name.Split(new string[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

   if (names.Count() > 0)
   {
      var firstInitial = names.First().ToUpper().First();
      var lastInitial = names.Last().ToUpper().First();

      if(!firstInitial.Equals(letter) && lastInitial.Equals(letter))
      {
         return names.Last();
      }
   }

   return string.Empty;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex worked for me fine

```
$array = ["Duncan, Jean","Schmidt, Paul","Sells, Simon","Martin, Jane","Smith, Peter","Stephens, Sheila"];
foreach($array as $el){
    if(preg_match('/([S].+)(?:,)( [^S].+)/',$el,$matches))
       echo $matches[2]."<br/>";
}
```

The Answer I got is

```
Paul
Peter
```

Comment: But in this case, i want to extract the last name only.

Comment: You mean to chop out and print the last name only?

Answer (score 0):

In you current regex you capture the lastname in a capturing group and match the rest in a non capturing group.

If you change your non capturing group `(?:` into a positive lookahead `(?=` you would only capture the lastname.

[`([S].+)(?=, [^S])`](https://regex101.com/r/qRzt4F/1) or a bit shorter [`S.+(?=, [^S])`](https://regex101.com/r/qRzt4F/2)