# replaceAll and regex groups‽

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have recently completed the following programming exercise: [Acronym Generator](https://www.codewars.com/kata/576a599359b11651bc00040e)

The statement is:

> In nearly every company each employee has a certain acronym containing
>   the first characters of his first and last name(s).
>
> Your task is to write an acronym generator which generates an acronym
>   for a given name. You don't have to care about duplicate acronyms
>   (someone else will do this for you). Note that names can be given in
>   upper or in lower case. The acronym shall always be upper case.
>
> Normally the acronym is always the first letter of your first and the
>   first letter of the last name in upper case.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> Thomas Meyer => TM
>
> martin schmidt => MS
> ```
>
> In your company there work only people with a maxinmum of two first
>   names. If a person has two first names, they might be joined with a
>   dash.
>
> ```
> Jan-Erich Schmidt => JES Jan Erich Mueller => JEM
> ```
>
> Last names may also be joined with a dash. No one can have more than
>   two last names.
>
> ```
> Paul Meyer-Schmidt
> ```
>
> In Germany, there are last names which have the leading word "von".
>   This shall be abbreviated with a lower case "v":
>
> ```
> Paul von Lahnstein => PvL
>
> Martin von Lahnstein-Meyer => MvLM
> ```

I have completed the exercise and I am trying to understand other people's answers. I have found one which uses replaceAll and regex. You can see this solution [in this link.](https://www.codewars.com/kata/reviews/576a8d69cdd98d7959001e96/groups/5a68f190d6660f4da6000479)

```
public class AcronymGenerator {
  public static String createAcronym(String lastName, String firstName) {
    firstName = firstName.toUpperCase().replaceAll("(.)([A-Z])*([-| ])?(.)?(.)*", "$1$4");
    String von = lastName.toLowerCase().replaceAll("^((v)(on ))?(.)*", "$2");
    lastName = lastName.toUpperCase().replaceAll("(VON )?(.)([A-Z])*([-| ])?(.)?(.)*", "$2$5");
    return firstName+von+lastName;
  }
}
```

I guess what he does is replace names by their initial in capital letters, von by the v, and surnames by their initial in capital letters. However, I do not understand how the groups of regular expressions work when used within replaceAll

Could you explain how replaceAll() works with regex groups? I would like to understand how it works:

```
replaceAll("(.)([A-Z])*([-| ])?(.)?(.)*", "$1$4");
replaceAll("^((v)(on ))?(.)*", "$2");
replaceAll("(VON )?(.)([A-Z])*([-| ])?(.)?(.)*", "$2$5");
```

I have also read:
[Java: Understanding the String replaceAll() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189415/java-understanding-the-string-replaceall-method/5189447)
[What is a non-capturing group in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions)
[How to Extract people's last name start with "S" and first name not start with "S"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51894318/how-to-extract-peoples-last-name-start-with-s-and-first-name-not-start-with)

Comment: I’m just wondering how to split a full name correctly into first and last name before calling `createAcronym(String lastName, String firstName)`. Of course it can be done, it just doesn’t seem trivial under the rules given.

Comment: @OleV.V. It is very trivial if you ask the user to input first name in one field and last name in another field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In regex, `()` parentheses are used to define a **group**. If the first character inside the parentheses is a `?`, then it's a **non-capturing group**<sup>1</sup>, otherwise it's a **capturing group**.

<sup>1) Except that `(?<name>X)` is a named capturing group.</sup>

*Examples:* `A(FOO)B` will match the string `"AFOOB"` and will *capture* the string `"FOO"`. `A(?:FOO)B` will match the string `"AFOOB"` and will not capture anything.

Since a regex can have more than one capture group, they are identified by position, starting with the first `(` being capture group **1**.

*Example:* `A(X)B(?:Y)C(Z)` will match the string `"AXBYCZ"` and will *capture* `"X"` as group 1, and `"Z"` as group 2. Non-capturing groups don't count.

So, in your example:

```
replaceAll("(.)([A-Z])*([-| ])?(.)?(.)*", "$1$4");
            ↑  ↑       ↑       ↑   ↑
            1  2       3       4   5
```

If a group is optional (directly as here, or inside a bigger optional group), then the captured value is null when retrieved by calling `group(n)` on the `Matcher`, or a blank string when referenced using the `$n` syntax in a replacement value (as shown here).

The regex above it actually capturing too much, and is incorrectly using `|` in a character class, and would be better written as:

```
replaceAll("(.)[A-Z]*[- ]?(.)?.*", "$1$2");
            ↑             ↑
            1             2
```